# Java, converting from hexadecimal to decimal using casting

Tags: java, hex

I found an exercise to convert from hex to decimal using casting, but I did not understand how that `decimal + 'A' - 10` worked. Can anybody explain me?

code is here:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class Test {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("Please enter a decimal value (0-15):");
         int decimal = input.nextInt();

         if (decimal <= 9 && decimal >= 0) {
             System.out.println("The hex value is: " + decimal);

         }

         else if (decimal >= 10 && decimal <= 15) {
             System.out.println("The hex value is " + (char)(decimal + 'A' - 10));

         }

         else {
             System.out.println("It's an invalid input.");
         }
     }
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: a `char` itself represents an `int` aswell. so by doing `char` + `int` you can get either a `char` or `int`

Comment: What have you done to try to figure it out; have you looked at an ascii table and tried to see what's happening here?

Comment: Why not ask your professor or teaching assistant for help? That is literally their job. Explaining it will also help them hone in on what other concepts you didn't understand that they may have expected you to understand when they presented this code. In other words, we can only really provide the mechanical answer; your professor is in a much better position to help you learn whatever or is they wanted you to learn from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alphabetical characters in Unicode have sequential codes:

```
A = 65
B = 66
C = 67
D = 68
...
```

So, the value of `(char)('A'+1)` is the same as `'B'`, as the `char` value `'A'` is interpreted as 65 when used in an arithmetic expression, and then the +1 makes it 66, and then you cast it as char again, it's `'B'`.

So what you have there is the value of `'A'` plus the difference between the `decimal` and 10 (which is 0 through 5). This will give you the values `'A' + 0`, `'A' + 1`, `'A' + 2` etc, which means `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'` respectively when you calculate it.

Answer (score 0):

Each char has integer value associated with it. Hence casting int to (char) will yield to char value.